Configuring dnsmasq so I can use short host names
I have set up dnsmasq on my local network that consists of Linux/macOS computers. I have added a line like this in my /etc/dnsmasq.d/home.lan file:
dhcp-host=dc:cd:2f:bf:44:12,printer,192.168.0.3

I was hoping/expecting that would mean I can use a command like:
ping printer

from all the machines on my network, but it cannot resolve it. I know that dnsmasq is working to some extent because the printer requests an IP address when it starts up and configures itself to the correct IP address above.
I want to keep all DNS/DHCP configuration in /etc/dnsmasq.d/home.lan as far as possible, rather than editing /etc/hosts or anything else, either on the DNS server or any clients.
I researched and found this so I also tried adding:
host-record=printer,192.168.0.3

but that didn't help either.

Here is my config file, running on latest Raspberry Pi OS with the latest dnsmasq:
# General configuration
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-hosts
server=8.8.8.8
server=1.1.1.1
dhcp-range=192.168.0.3,192.168.0.200,4h
dhcp-authoritative

# Set default gateway and DNS server for DHCP clients
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.0.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.0.2

# Logging
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
log-queries

# Reserved IPs
dhcp-host=c8:7f:5f:df:0f:08,router,192.168.0.1
dhcp-host=dc:ab:3f:bf:bb:ab,dnsserver,192.168.0.2
dhcp-host=dc:cd:2f:bf:44:12,printer,192.168.0.3


As requested in the comments, if I try this:
dig printer @192.168.0.2

I get:
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-1~deb12u2-Debian <<>> printer @192.168.0.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 18880
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;printer.           IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.2#53(192.168.0.2) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 20 13:25:32 BST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36

In the log at /var/log/dnsmasq.log, I see:
query [A] printer from 192.168.0.2
config printer is NXDOMAIN


Note that my router is at 192.168.0.1 and the machine running dnsmasq is at 192.168.0.2

Assuming 192.168.0.2 is where dnsmasq is running, what does dig printer @192.168.0.2 output?

@muru Thank you for taking the time to look. I have added the information you requested. And yes, the dnsmasq is running on 192.168.0.2.

I wonder if it is related to ndots, whatever that is in here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666032/638384 If it is related, how do I set the search domain from dnsmasq for all clients without having to edit files on all the clients on my network?

A direct dig printer @192.168.0.2 shouldn't involve ndots. That said, how is /etc/dnsmasq.d/home.lan being included in the main dnsmasq config? I don't see a conf-dir line

You are seeing the file I have included, so there is no directive in there to include the file. It is included because of the way dnsmasq.service starts dnsmasq like this /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service

Ah, since you mentioned adding host-record=printer,192.168.0.3 but it's not in there, I assumed you were talking about two separate files. Was the dig query with or without that line?

I get the same results with and without the host-record line.

You can't have your DNS server as a DHCP entry. It must have a static address and therefore an A record

I think I have solved it - and it was probably caused by not having a set a "search domain".
I added the following two lines to my dnsmasq config file and things work considerably better:
domain=localnet
# Tell DHCP clients the search domain
dhcp-option=option:domain-name,localnet


I'm still working on the dnsmasq settings and may add improvements later. If anyone can confirm/explain my answer with a few words of clarification that would be great.
